# Would a loan repayment appearing in bank statement affect visa application

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I work as a doctor in my country and I am applying for a standard 6 months uk visa to enable me write the plab 2 examination which can only be taken in the uk. My dilemma is that I am planning on taking a bank loan in addition to my savings to enable me afford all the cost of the examinations.

I intend taking the loan well in advance of the 6 months statement required. But the bank statement would show monthly repayment from the account.

Would the presence of a loan repayment on my bank statement negatively affect my visa application. Is there any way to go around it so it doesn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?] The section on Proportionality appears relevant to your situation (https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: This was very insightful as it cleared some areas I still needed answers to but my particular case isn't exactly answered by the post.

Comment: A loan repayment will be considered like any other recurring charge you pay, like rent or a mortgage repayment or utility bills, etc. It will be deducted from your income to determine your monthly available income and determine if the cost of the trip as you describe it is consistent with your available income. Here it may actually be counterproductive, as the cost of the trip will probably be counted twice, once as loan repayments and once as taken out of your available income. The result will vary a lot based on what the actual figures are.

Comment: How significant is the monthly repayment compared to your monthly salary?

Comment: One way to avoid any negative impression would be to wait until you’ve paid off the loan before you apply for the visa. Or wait until you have saved enough to fund the trip without needing a loan. What % of the trip cost is the loan?

Comment: Read this QA too: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e